# CSS help needed. Something really wrong

Tags: html, css

Third chat message should be same as first chat message. its even a wrong direction and color.
[image: This is my problem.]
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pto8ce70/)

CSS

..........................................................................................................................................................

```
.chat {
    max-height: 570px; 
    overflow: auto; 
    margin: 0 0 30px 0; 
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; 
    background-color: #fff;
}

.chat .message { 
    float: left; 
    clear: both; 
    max-width: 80%; 
    padding: 0 0 20px 0; 
    position: relative; 
}

.chat .message:first-child { 
    padding-top: 20px; 
}

.chat .message.in { 
    float: left;
}

.chat .message.out { 
    float: right;
}

.chat .message img.avatar {
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
}

.chat .message.in img.avatar {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.chat .message.out img.avatar {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.chat .message .content { 
    padding: 12px 14px;
    position: relative;
}

.chat .message.in .content { 
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #65CEA7;
    margin-left: 58px; 

}
.chat .message.out .content { 
    color: #333; 
    background-color: #EFF0F4;
    margin-right: 58px; 
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5; 
}

.chat .message.in .content:after { 
    border-top: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); 
    border-right: 6px solid #65CEA7; 
    border-bottom: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); 
    left: -6px; top: 13px; 
    position: absolute; 
    margin-left: 0; 
    content: ''; 
}

.chat .message.out .content:before { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 12px; 
    right: 0; 
    display: inline-block; 
    border-top: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-left: 7px solid #e5e5e5; 
    border-bottom: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); 
    border-left-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); 
    content: ''; 
    margin-right: -7px; 
}

.chat .message.out .content:after { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 13px; 
    right: 1px; 
    left: auto; 
    display: inline-block; 
    border-top: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); 
    border-left: 6px solid #fff; 
    border-bottom: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-right: 0; 
    content: ''; 
    margin-right: -7px; 
}

.chat .message .content .name {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.chat .message.in .content a.name{
    color: #fff;
}

.chat .message.out .content a.name {
    color: #333;
}

.chat .message .content .date {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.chat .message.in .content .date {
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.chat .message.out .content .date {
    color: #000000;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.chat .message .content .body { 
    padding-left: 1px;
}

.chat .message .content, 
.chat .message img.avatar {
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
```

### }

### HTML

```
<div class="chat">
        <div class="message in">
            <img src="http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130220074109/halo/images/8/8d/USER_Sgt_D_Grif_avatar.png" alt="" class="avatar">
            <div class="content">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="name">Margaret J. Collins</a>
                <span class="date">at Mar 12, 2014 6:13</span>
                <div class="body">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.                       
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="message out">
            <img src="http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130220074109/halo/images/8/8d/USER_Sgt_D_Grif_avatar.png" alt="" class="avatar">
                <div class="content">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="name">Joseph R. Colston</a>
                <span class="date">at Mar 12, 2014 6:13</span>
                <div class="body">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.        
                </div>
            <div>
        </div>
        <div class="message in">
            <img src="http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130220074109/halo/images/8/8d/USER_Sgt_D_Grif_avatar.png" alt="" class="avatar">
            <div class="content">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="name">Margaret J. Collins</a>
                <span class="date">at Mar 12, 2014 6:13</span>
                <div class="body">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.                       
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were putting the answer in the message out div. So it was a html markup problem.

```css
.chat {
  max-height: 570px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.chat .message {
  float: left;
  max-width: 80%;
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  position: relative;
}
.chat .message:first-child {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.chat .message.in {
  float: left;
}
.chat .message.out {
  float: right;
}
.chat .message img.avatar {
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
}
.chat .message.in img.avatar {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.chat .message.out img.avatar {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.chat .message .content {
  padding: 12px 14px;
  position: relative;
}
.chat .message.in .content {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #65CEA7;
  margin-left: 58px;
}
.chat .message.out .content {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #EFF0F4;
  margin-right: 58px;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.chat .message.in .content:after {
  border-top: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-right: 6px solid #65CEA7;
  border-bottom: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  left: -6px;
  top: 13px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 0;
  content: '';
}
.chat .message.out .content:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  right: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-left: 7px solid #e5e5e5;
  border-bottom: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-left-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  content: '';
  margin-right: -7px;
}
.chat .message.out .content:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 1px;
  left: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-left: 6px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-right: 0;
  content: '';
  margin-right: -7px;
}
.chat .message .content .name {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.chat .message.in .content a.name {
  color: #fff;
}
.chat .message.out .content a.name {
  color: #333;
}
.chat .message .content .date {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.chat .message.in .content .date {
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.chat .message.out .content .date {
  color: #000000;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.chat .message .content .body {
  padding-left: 1px;
}
.chat .message .content,
.chat .message img.avatar {
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">
  <div class="message in">
    <img src="http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130220074109/halo/images/8/8d/USER_Sgt_D_Grif_avatar.png" alt="" class="avatar">
    <div class="content"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="name">Margaret J. Collins</a>
      <span class="date">at Mar 12, 2014 6:13</span>

      <div class="body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="message out">
    <img src="http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130220074109/halo/images/8/8d/USER_Sgt_D_Grif_avatar.png" alt="" class="avatar">
    <div class="content"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="name">Joseph R. Colston</a>
      <span class="date">at Mar 12, 2014 6:13</span>

      <div class="body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="message in">
    <img src="http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130220074109/halo/images/8/8d/USER_Sgt_D_Grif_avatar.png" alt="" class="avatar">
    <div class="content"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="name">Margaret J. Collins</a>
      <span class="date">at Mar 12, 2014 6:13</span>

      <div class="body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

is this your expected output? **[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pto8ce70/1/)** 
pull out your `"message in"` from  `"message out"` div

```
<div class="chat">
    <div class="message in">
        <img src="http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130220074109/halo/images/8/8d/USER_Sgt_D_Grif_avatar.png" alt="" class="avatar">
        <div class="content">   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="name">Margaret J. Collins</a>
 <span class="date">at Mar 12, 2014 6:13</span>

            <div class="body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="message out">
        <img src="http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130220074109/halo/images/8/8d/USER_Sgt_D_Grif_avatar.png" alt="" class="avatar">
        <div class="content">   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="name">Joseph R. Colston</a>
 <span class="date">at Mar 12, 2014 6:13</span>

            <div class="body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="message in">
        <img src="http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130220074109/halo/images/8/8d/USER_Sgt_D_Grif_avatar.png" alt="" class="avatar">
        <div class="content">   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="name">Margaret J. Collins</a>
 <span class="date">at Mar 12, 2014 6:13</span>

            <div class="body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```